# Sluggish unresponsive touches on Android

Tags: android

I am porting my game, from iOS to Android. Mostly, it's working just fine. I'm mostly using C/C++ code, with the NDK / JNI, and a little Java to manage the app life-cycle and send touches and accelerometer info to my game.

As far as I can tell, there are 2 threads, the main UI thread, and a thread created by GLSurfaceView to handle display and flipping OpenGL back-buffers etc.

So, all is working well, apart from the touches. They feel sluggish and unresponsive, compared to other apps I have tried on my devices. After doing some research, I believe the issue may relate to how I am using threads. Specifically, I think, it could be related to not sleeping the display thread after it does it's work, and so, it's holding things up on the main UI thread. Does that sound plausible?

I tried computing how many ms I need the GLSurfaceView display thread to sleep, and then sleep(), and it improves the touches, but the animation is no longer a constant 60FPS on my devices. My suspicion is that I am computing the number of ms to sleep for the previous frame, and using that number to sleep for the current frame.

Or, it could be something altogether different? I don't know. I'm still very new to Android...

Hope someone can shed some light on the matter, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Could please show us some code, or pseudocode, to illustrate how are you doing things now? We cannot help you without any informations about current state

Comment: Sorry for vague response but I seem to recall seeing similar questions and the answer was to sleep on the input thread after receiving a touch-- otherwise the input thread spins too fast.

Comment: @antlersoft That could be the case.  Some phones might be just sending gobs of touch data to the app which can slow it down.  If he sleeps the UI thread though, he has to make sure anything not relying on touch is in a separate thread because that will slow down too.

Comment: @MarekSebera Would love to post some code. This is actually the first time I ever posted a question on SO, so unsure what the procedure for posting code is; do I just copy and paste it as a comment?

Comment: @antlersoft Just to clarify, is the input thread the same thing as the main UI thread?

Comment: @cosmic4z -- Yes, input thread is main UI thread

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sleep the GL thread.  In fact, I'd say sleeping the GL thread would make it even more sluggish since it's the thing rendering the images on the screen.

Sluggish UI is caused primarily by the main UI thread being held up.  If you're doing a lot of processing on the main thread (accelerometer data for example), the main thread will have to do the work first and THEN handle your user input.  This can give the "feeling" of sluggishness.  All touch events and non-opengl drawing events **must** happen in the UI thread.  Anything else can occur in a background thread which wouldn't block the UI thread for an extended period of time.

Aside from that, the other possibility is you're simply overloading the processor.  Your GL thread might be taking a long time to draw.  It's probably receiving and handling touch events and accelerometer data.  However, if the render takes a really long time, then you'd be seeing out-dated data.  Thus, it again feels "sluggish".  You mentioned that it's not a constant 60 FPS so this is a very real possibility.  You may have optimize your drawing code so the render is faster.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing anything intensive on the main UI thread, essentially, I'm just recording accelerometer and touch data. Which I don't think should take that long. I'll remove the accelerometer stuff, and see if that helps.

Comment: No.  That doesn't sound like it would hold up the UI to me. It could be a slow render or too much data is being sent.

Comment: I don't believe I'm overloading the processor (could be wrong though). I call my 'update game' and 'render game' both from the GLSurfaceView renderer's onDrawFrame. From there, I call C/C++ code to update and render the game. I did try updating and then render the game like 4 times, and it was still fast, which makes me think I'm not pushing the GPU too hard.

Comment: Okay, I have 2 threads. The UI thread, which processes (stores in a buffer) touch data. The GLSurefaceView renderer thread, which updates and renders the game. From what you say, I suspect the UI thread is being held up for some reason. I'm a little stumped though, as the UI thread is doing so little. Anyone have any more suggestions?

Comment: There's a number of possibilities.  I just listed the ones that are usually the cause for "sluggish" feeling that I've encountered most.  It doesn't seem like the UI (main) thread is doing much, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It *could* be the opposite. As stated in the comments above, that you're registering *too much* information.  Slowing down the main thread *very slightly* would remedy that which would allow the render thread to catch up.  It could make it worse if too slow, but slowing it down, say, 50ms might help. It *could be* that somewhere in your logic you're losing data. This would mean that your render thread isn't responding to all input.  Can you better describe what you mean by "sluggish"?

Comment: Thank you Deev. Okay, sluggish means; when I touch the screen it seems to take a while to respond, when I release my finger, again, it takes a while to register. When I say a while, it's perhaps 30-70ms (estimate). My game is running at 60FPS on both my devices, it's a top-down racing game; the touch delay makes it almost unplayable, compared with the iOS version, or Android version running on the Nexus7 (it's the Samsung Galaxy S2 that is the problem device). I tried one of the multi-touch apps on my S2, and it feels a lot more responsive. I wonder if I am processing the touches correctly?

Comment: I mean, I am not processing the history aspect of the touch data. Here is my onTouchEvent: http://pastie.org/4676472 (the onTouchEventN is a native function, where I just store touch data in a buffer, for use by the game, which runs on a separate thread to the main UI thread).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that method.  I'm sorry that I'm not more helpful.  The only thing I can think of is the Galaxy S2 is handling the events wrong or slow.  This is only noted because the Nexus 7 doesn't have the problem (although the Nexus 7 is also faster).

Comment: It's okay, and thank you for trying and offering your insights. What puzzles me, is that other games on the S2 do not suffer from this; or at least, they don't seem to.